# PDF Axial Shading Pattern ranging opacity

Tags: pdf, design-patterns, alpha-transparency

I'm trying to figure out the way to have in PDF (say 1.4) an axial shading pattern but such that the opacity of the colors ranges along the shading, not just the colors themselves.

This is naturally supported in rendering systems, such as GDI+, where the alpha channel is in the color. But in PDF, the opacity is controlled separatedly, so in the case of a shading, I have no idea where to specify that.

Please notice that my question is about PDF itself (as in the spec), regardless of any PDF generation library/software.

(yet OTOH, if there is a C++ library that can be used to *produce* PDF documents and supports that type of shading directly, I'd love to hear about it)

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can implement this using a soft mask in the graphics state. The soft mask would be based on a similar axial shading that would define the opacity level.
Then you draw the softmask and the colored axial shading in the same location so that you get variable opacity for the colored shading.

Comment: You are exactly right! I was told to do just that by someone (presumably from Adobe) in a PDF forum, and it worked like a charm :)